Error excuting `kubectl create -f` with root?
I've been studying Kubernetes for a week to apply it to a side project. But just now, I met a problem which seemed to be an issue with my Ubuntu account.
Create pod
If I run kubectl create -f  command with my default account of GCP Web SSH, it works without problem.
Error
However, If I ran same command with the root account, it crashes and the following error message appears:
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "http-go-pod-v2.yaml": pods "http-go" is forbidden: pod does not have "kubernetes.io/config.mirror" annotation, node "master-1" can only create mirror pods
Why can't the root account run?
I found out that there is no problem if I use the default account, but I want to solve this problem from the cause with detail...

Kubernetes will by default try to connect to the server described in $HOME/.kube/config, but the home directory will be different for the root user, so you could be using a different cluster or a different user configuration.  Kubernetes usually uses YAML-format manifest files, not PNG images; did you mean to include the YAML and error message in plain text?

I'm not really sure how you setup Kubernetes (kubeadm?) but when you are running your kubectl command as 'root' it's trying to create a mirror pod which is typically only reserved for the kubelet to create for static pods.
More on static pods: Whats the difference between "Pods" and "Static Pods" in kubernetes and when to choose "static pods" over regular pods
